# Check which ebextensions have been run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have an environment in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk that is proving problematic. I'm trying to check which ebextensions have run because there is an oddity where I see a logrotate conf file created but the contents are not what I've written.

Does anyone know which log file I can find that information in? I've tried /var/log/eb-engine.log but that doesn't seem to have anything about running ebextensions. eb-activity, and eb-commandprocessor are mentioned in the docs but they don't exist on the instance.

Platform: Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amazon Linux 2 is still being worked on some log files aren't available yet. So says AWS Support.

However, you can see which ebextensions have been run by looking in cfn-init.log, and cfn-init-cmd.log.

I was searching for the file names rather than the command names so I couldn't see where the results were being logged.